# JAVA: Comparing an object from another class to an object

Tags: java, equals, instanceof

I have in a class the following code...

```
String processor()
{
  Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
  while (curr < infixExpr.length())
  {
     // assigning the current index position of string in infix expression to a variable to reduce amount of repeated code
     Character element = infixExpr.charAt(curr);

     if (isOperand(element))
     {
        postfixExpr += "" + element;
     }
     else if (element == '(')
     {
        stack.push(element);
     }
     else if (element == ')')
     {
        while (!stack.peek().equals('('))
        {
           postfixExpr += stack.pop(); // adding all items in stack after ( and before )
        }
        stack.pop(); // this should pop the stack of the  waiting pushed ( paren and remove it from our postfix expression, basically ignoring it
        // right paren found to trigger this else if statement was never pushed onto the stack nor assigned to the postfix expression, also ignored
     }
     else //*must be an operator then
     {
        while (OrdOpsTable.getOperatorPrecedence(stack.peek(), true) > OrdOpsTable.getOperatorPrecedence(element, false)) // flag, 'true' to signify this is from the stack. ALso, compare if it has higher precedence over the current operator
        {
           postfixExpr += stack.pop(); // placing found operator to end of postfix expression
        }
        stack.push(element);
     }
     curr++;
  }
  while (!stack.isEmpty())
  {
     postfixExpr += stack.pop();
  }
  return postfixExpr;
}
```

In the method "getOperatorPrecedence" parameters, I have a Stack instance called **stack**, calling the method *peek*, returning a Character Object. As the field *element* shows, element is of Character Object type. I created a simple flag boolean in the method parameters to make this simple.

So, the "getOperatorPrecedence" is in another class file called "OrdOpsTable"...

```
public final class OrdOpsTable<T> extends ArrayList
{
    // INITIALIZERS
    private static Character[] table = {'(','+','-','*','/','%','^'};
    private static ArrayList<OperatorValues> ON_stack = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<OperatorValues> ON_curr = new ArrayList<>();
    private T FROM_stack = null;
    private T FROM_curr = null;

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    private OrdOpsTable(T curr)
    {
        setOperatorPrecedence();
        if (curr.getClass() == Stack.class)
            this.FROM_stack = curr;
        else
            this.FROM_curr = curr;
    }

    // METHODS
    private static void setOperatorPrecedence()
    {
        // this method just sets the unique values of each operator to two arrays
        int i = 0;
        for (char op : table)
        {
            switch(op)
            {
                case '(':
                    ON_stack.add(i, new OperatorValues(op, 0));
                    ON_curr.add(i, new OperatorValues(op, 100));
                    break;
                case '+':
                    ON_stack.add(i, new OperatorValues(op, 2));
                    ON_curr.add(i, new OperatorValues(op, 1));
                    break;
                case '-':
                    ON_stack.add(i, new OperatorValues(op, 2));
                    ON_curr.add(i, new OperatorValues(op, 1));
                    break;
                case '*':
                    ON_stack.add(i, new OperatorValues(op, 4));
                    ON_curr.add(i, new OperatorValues(op, 3));
                    break;
                case '/':
                    ON_stack.add(i, new OperatorValues(op, 4));
                    ON_curr.add(i, new OperatorValues(op, 3));
                    break;
                case '%':
                    ON_stack.add(i, new OperatorValues(op, 4));
                    ON_curr.add(i, new OperatorValues(op, 3));
                    break;
                case '^':
                    ON_stack.add(i, new OperatorValues(op, 5));
                    ON_curr.add(i, new OperatorValues(op, 6));
                    break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }


    public static int getOperatorPrecedence(Object curr, boolean FROM_stack)
    {
        setOperatorPrecedence();
        if (FROM_stack)
        {
            return ON_stack.get(ON_stack.indexOf(curr)).value;
        }
        else
        {
            return ON_curr.get(ON_stack.indexOf(curr)).value;
        }
    }



    /* SUBCLASS */
    private static class OperatorValues
    {   
        // FIELDS
        private char operator;
        private int value;

        // CONSTRUCTOR
        OperatorValues(char operator, int value)
        {
            this.operator = operator;
            this.value = value;
        }

        // METHOD
        char getOperator()
        {
            return this.operator;
        }
        int getValue()
        {
            return this.value;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            return this.operator;
        }
    }
```

What I need help with is finding a way to correctly return the OperatorValue subclass field **value** for both instances of

```
return ON_stack.get(ON_stack.indexOf(curr)).value;
                      and
return ON_curr.get(ON_stack.indexOf(curr)).value;
```

I'm getting the following error...

```
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
            at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:431)
            at OrdOpsTable.getOperatorPrecedence(OrdOpsTable.java:79)
            at PostfixParser.processor(PostfixParser.java:57)
            at InfixPostfixTester.main(InfixPostfixTester.java:78)
```

It appears when I debug and follow this, the issue is in "Character" class "equals". First, when I force step into the first return statement in question, it goes to the indexOf() in ArrayList...

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

When the debugger hits the .equals method in here, it goes into the Character class...

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Character) {
        return value == ((Character)obj).charValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

The issue here is that the IF statement in this equals method is failing at this comparison. It seems it's comparing obj as my custom made OperatorValues class's toString() and it is obviously not an instanceof a Character class. So, it's failing because it's comparing "(" as a Character. I need it to compare '(' to trigger 'true' in this method.

For an example, I assigned the char '(' with an int of '0' in one array and '100' in another array as you can see above in my OrdOpsTable class in the method setOperatorPrecedence(). When the Character class equals() method is called here without using OperatorValues class's toString(), my debugger says the inline value for curr's '(' in this equal method shows, "obj: OrdOpsTable$OperatorValues@636.

If there was a way to make my toString() method in OperatorValues return a Character instead of String. This of course would cause an error if I did so. Any suggestions on what you would do here?

*NOTE: Let me know if I need to provide more info for you. This is a homework assignment from a class, I've spent alot of time stuck on this part and I've tried relentlessly. I need some outsourcing help to understand what I'm missing.

Comment: Please correct the code and make sure to post a code that compiles with errors.

Comment: Regardless of their relevance, replacing identifier names with strings makes the code hard to read and confusing.  You need to provide an [mcve] that can be compiled. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggested edits guys. I'm new here. :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I changed everything that was of Character class to String class and in my OrdOpsTable class, getOperatorPrecedence() method, to force the comparison from its native class of my custom OperatorValues class to String class, I did this...

```
return ON_stack.get(ON_stack.toString().indexOf(curr)).getValue();
```

Thanks everyone who did pitch in for the help, appreciate it.